# ActionView, Application.html.erb and HTML head tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, title, meta, actionview

I have a simple question regarding Ruby on Rails, ActionView, Application.html.erb and the use of HTML head tags.

I know that application.html.erb is used for displaying content across all pages on your site.

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="My desciprtion.">
  <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
  <title><%= @title %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true, :cache => "cache/all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", :async => true, "data-turbolinks-track" => true, :cache => "cache/all" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

That means, the above code is displayed on all of my web pages.

Now, I've been reading about SEO and it suggests using seperate description meta tags for every web page, to tell search engines what a page is about. My question to you is

Are you allowed to customize individual pages in rails like

```
page1.html.erb
page2.html.erb
page3.html.erb
```

and include the HTML head tag inside them?

I've been working with Ruby on Rails for quite some time, but I have never seen a head tag inside a view page.

I haven't seen a body tag to for that matter.

I have used

```
<% @title = "Page Title" %>
```

to declare individual titles for pages. That would be the equivalent of HTML Title tag.

Is there something similar for declaring a description for every web page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could alter your header to:

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <%= yield :meta %>
  <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
  <title><%= yield :title %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true, :cache => "cache/all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", :async => true, "data-turbolinks-track" => true, :cache => "cache/all" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

Then in your views you can do:

```
<% content_for :meta do %>
  <meta name="description" content="blah">
<% end %>

<% content_for :title, 'My title' %>
```

Comment: OMG, I wasted my lot of time, Your answer worked like a champ!!!!! thank you

Answer (score 0):

you could use [meta-tag](https://github.com/kpumuk/meta-tags) gem:

```
<head>
  ...
  <%= display_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

as some examples:

```
set_meta_tags site: 'Site Title', title: 'Member Login'
# <title>Site Title | Page Title</title>

set_meta_tags description: "All text about keywords, other keywords"
# <meta name="description" content="All text about keywords, other keywords" />

set_meta_tags canonical: "http://yoursite.com/canonical/url"
# <link rel="canonical" href="http://yoursite.com/canonical/url" />

set_meta_tags :twitter => {
  :card => "summary",
  :site => "@username"
}
# <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary"/>
# <meta name="twitter:site" content="@username"/>

set_meta_tags :author => "Dmytro Shteflyuk"
# <meta name="author" content="Dmytro Shteflyuk"/>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @SørenHoltenHansen, but if gem will be deleted and link will be incorrect, this answer also will be incorrect, doesn't matter what explanation I add to it;)

Comment: It matters big time what explanation you add to it. Quality questions and quality answers is what sets Stack Overflow apart from virtually any other Q/A sites.

Comment: any way, I changed it